# Swift - get UIImage from UIColllectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `collectionView` where each `cell` contains a `UIImage` and an empty `UIButton` .  How do I the picture that the user tapped on?

```
class ImageCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    @IBOutlet weak var imageCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    let images: [UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "beerImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "christmasImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "goalImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "travelImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "rollerImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "giftImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "shirtImage")!,
        UIImage(named: "dressImage")!,

    ]

    let columnLayout = FlowLayout(
        itemSize: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150),
        minimumInteritemSpacing: 30,
        minimumLineSpacing: 10,
        sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 10, right: 20)
    )

    var colViewWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        self.imageCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = columnLayout

        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageCollectionView.dataSource = self
        imageCollectionView.delegate = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

        cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.item]
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func imageButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("tapped")
    }


    @IBAction func closeButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let HomeViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC") as! ExampleViewController
                self.present(HomeViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Update**

In the end I would like to pass that image to another ViewController. I tried it this way but the picture isn't showing up in the other ViewController:

***ViewControllerA***

```
var tappedImage = UIImage()
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tappedImage = images[indexPath.row]
}

var showPopUpView = true

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print(showPopUpView)
    var vc = segue.destination as! ExampleViewController
    vc.pickedImage = self.tappedImage
    vc.ShowPopUpView = self.showPopUpView

}
```

***ViewControllerB***

```
    var pickedImage = UIImage()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePreview.image = pickedImage
```

Comment: Did you try `didSelectItem...atIndexPath...` ?

Comment: no, how would I do that? sorry, quite new to Swift

Comment: Like the way you used `...cellForItemAt indexPath...` and there is no need for that emptyButton

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini could you have a look at my updated question? :)

Comment: Probably your issue is with the order of the flow you are using.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duo to the conversation in comments:

The order of actions should be:

1. User clicks on a cell
2. Fetching the image according to the `indexPath` of the selected cell
3. Setting it in a temporary variable (`tappedImage`)
4. Performing segue
5. Pass the temporary image to the destination's temporary image (`pickedImage`)
6. Loading the destination's view
7. Show the image.

Seems like you are missing one of these steps ( probably the step 3, since you are not calling `performSegue` in the `...didSelectItemAt indexPath...` and it maybe not getting called at all! Try print something there and check if it's true )

Or you may disorder the flow ( probably you setting the image **after** destination's `View` is loaded and the result is to not seeing that. )

#### Debug:

Try printing all variables you have access (e.g `tappedImage`, `pickedImage`, `images[indexPath.row]`, etc.) on each these 7 states and see where is the issue and where are you loosing the selected image reference

#### Possible issue

You are not using `...didSelectItemAt indexPath...` to `performSegue`, Probably you have a `UIButton` for that, so the button is blocking the `cell` from getting selected.

Comment: one more thing, I would like to pass that image now into my `cusotmCell`- Class. How can i do that?

Comment: You have already done that here `cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.item]`. I think you have another question. Please feel free to [ask another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). There is no much space in comments to ask and answer questions ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    imageToPass = images[indexPath.row]
}
```

Edit:
As far as passing that image to your next view controller, one possible way is to add a property to your first and second view controllers for the image, set that image in your `didSelectItemAt` call, then pass it using `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

```
let imageToPass: UIImage?

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifier == "identifier name here" {

       // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
       if let destVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
           // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
           destVC.image = imageToPass
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I want to pass it to another ViewController with a segue but the image is not showing up in the other Viewcontroller :/

Comment: I just saw your edit and it looks like you're already doing what I suggested.  If you put a breakpoint in prepare is that getting set before your segue happens?

Comment: I think it happens before, because I just added a `print("test")` inside `prepare` and it got printed

Comment: I've run into this before with segues but not in a while. If I remember what the issue was for me I'll update in here.

Comment: Is your segue from file owner to your next viewController or table view cell to your next viewController? I think setting it from file owner to your next viewController then calling performSegue(withIdentifier: "name here". sender: nil) after you set the image in didSelectItemAt should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202066/discussion-between-chris-and-tgrable).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let image = images[indexPath.row]
    //Result image
}
```

(or)
If you want to get image from button tap (Not recommended)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

   cell.imageView.image = images[indexPath.item]
   cell.layer.cornerRadius = 2

   //Replace your button
   cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row
   cell.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.imageButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

in button action

```
func imageButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
   let image = images[sender.tag]
   //Result image
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just edited my question. Could you have a look at it?

Comment: You can simply present the viewController without segue `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let tappedImage = images[indexPath.row]
            
            let nextVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourVCidentifier") as! ExampleViewController
            nextVC.pickedImage = self.tappedImage
            nextVC.ShowPopUpView = self.showPopUpView
            self.present(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }` @Chris

Comment: let my try that real quick

Comment: didn't work for me :/ now if I click on an image, nothing happens